# Progress bar Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve data for progress bar from database in my jsp page where it is being displayed in a table, but my Progress bar values are iterating on the first progress bar itself. i want progress bar value against all corresponding Goal id with progress bar values from database, but i am getting only on the first one.

FYI.. I am getting all the progress bar values which i have checked using alert statement.

```
<script>
    function progress(value1)
        {
            $(".progressBar").progressbar({value :value1});
    }
   </script>   

     <body>   
     <c:if test="${goal_list!= null }">
                <table class="fixed_headers">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Goal ID</th>
                            <th>Goal Progress Bar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${goal_list}" var="goal">
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="checkYourGoal.xyz?goal_ref_id=${goal.goal_ref_id}">${goal.goal_ref_id}</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="progressBar" id="progressbar1"></div>

                                        <script>
                                            var value = ${goal.goal_progress_value};
                                            progress(value);
                                        </script>                                   
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </c:if>
</body>


getting multiple progressbar but all values of progressbar are iterating within the first progressbar in the table.
```

Any suggestions. thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing an `each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function currently applies on each `.progressBar`. I would have said that each progress bar would then have the value of the last item but from what you're saying it's not. That part needs more investigation.

That being said, what you need is to store the pairs { progressBarId, value }.

```
<td>
    <div class="progressBar" id="progressBar${i}"></div>
    <input id="progressBar${i}_value" type="hidden" value="${goal.goal_progress_value}"/>
</td>
```

(${i} is obviously a counter)

Then, before the closing `</body>` tag you'll have something which will build your progress bar elements. It should retrieve the values of each progress bars and apply it to the corresponding DOM element.
It might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".progressBar").each(function() {
        var value = $("#" + this.id + "_value").val();
        $(this).progressbar({
            value :value
        });
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that JS code *should* be separated from HTML code.